# How do I access an image as a Drawable in AndroidStudio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm working on an android app using java in AndroidStudio. I have an `ImageView pic` and I want to set its image as a .png that I have saved in my `/drawable` folder. I may try

```
pic.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.image_name);
```

However, `setImageDrawable()` requires a Drawable, while `R.drawable.image_name` returns an Integer (the ID of the image).

---

How may I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setImageResource()` for this:

```
pic.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
```

---

More about it [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView#setImageResource(int))

Answer (score 0):

Use this for java

```
ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.drawable_resource_name);
```

and then set this drawable to your image view